# duda inner join a subconsulta

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, subconsultas

Alguien sabe como pasar esta consulta:

```
select
```

a un subconsulta :

```
Necesito sacar en esa query de subconsulta el nombre y apellido de la tabla usuario ... como podría hacer eso ya que esa consulta no tiene condición ..
```

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo el por qué de usar subconsultas si lo único que aporta es ineficiencia a esta query en particular, pero lo que se ocurre sería algo como:

```sql
select codigo, Nombre, Precio, Stock -- u.Nombre_apellido
from producto 
where codigo in (select  codigo_producto 
                 from compra 
                 where cantidad < 4 
                  and dni_usuario = any ( select dni 
                                          from usuarios usu
                                          where usu.dni = compra.dni_usuario)
                ) 
order by Nombre
```